# Why EF 6.13 left outer join with Lambda DefaultIfEmpty is Invalid?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, outer-join

Sorry, my English is very poor, I hope you understand.

If I use Linq it's correct, but now I want to use Lambda.

TABLE 1
ExamQuestion

TABLE 2
PaperQuestion

No foreign key;

```
var l = db.ExamQuestions
        .Join(db.PaperQuestions, s => s.Id, p => p.QuestionId, (s, p) => new
        ExamQuestionList()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Question = s.Question,
            CateTitle = "aaa",
            Option = s.Option,
            IsPass = s.IsPass,
            Answer = s.Answer,
            Difficulty = s.Difficulty,
            IsDelete = s.IsDelete,
            IsExist = true,
            Score = p.Score,
            CreateTime = s.CreateTime
        })

SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Question] AS [Question], 
N'aaa' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Option] AS [Option], 
[Extent1].[IsPass] AS [IsPass], 
[Extent1].[Answer] AS [Answer], 
[Extent1].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty], 
[Extent1].[IsDelete] AS [IsDelete], 
cast(1 as bit) AS [C2], 
[Extent2].[Score] AS [Score], 
[Extent1].[CreateTime] AS [CreateTime]
FROM  [dbo].[ExamQuestions] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PaperQuestions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[QuestionId]
```

I user DefaulifEmpty but invalid, left outer join nest Outermost layer

```
var l = db.ExamQuestions
        .Join(db.PaperQuestions, s => s.Id, p => p.QuestionId, (s, p) => new
        ExamQuestionList()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Question = s.Question,
            CateTitle = "aaa",
            Option = s.Option,
            IsPass = s.IsPass,
            Answer = s.Answer,
            Difficulty = s.Difficulty,
            IsDelete = s.IsDelete,
            IsExist = true,
            Score = p.Score,
            CreateTime = s.CreateTime
        }).DefaultIfEmpty();


SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Question] AS [Question], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Option] AS [Option], 
[Project1].[IsPass] AS [IsPass], 
[Project1].[Answer] AS [Answer], 
[Project1].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty], 
[Project1].[IsDelete] AS [IsDelete], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[Score] AS [Score], 
[Project1].[CreateTime] AS [CreateTime]
FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Question] AS [Question], 
    [Extent1].[Option] AS [Option], 
    [Extent1].[Answer] AS [Answer], 
    [Extent1].[CreateTime] AS [CreateTime], 
    [Extent1].[Difficulty] AS [Difficulty], 
    [Extent1].[IsPass] AS [IsPass], 
    [Extent1].[IsDelete] AS [IsDelete], 
    [Extent2].[Score] AS [Score], 
    N'aaa' AS [C1], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[ExamQuestions] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PaperQuestions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[QuestionId] ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: What does "invalid" mean? you should specify..

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid sql statement that it was generated by the linq provider and posted by you in the OP..

The most outer table `[SingleRowTable1]` allows to get always at least a single empty record composed by null fields named with the aliases specified in the statement by the column names prefixed with `[Project1]` table alias name.

The final join condition `AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1` clause bind all rows getted by the inner most projection to the outer most fictitious table `( SELECT 1 AS X )` that get always 1 value annd attach it to each row getted by the innermost projection.

I hope it is a clear explanation..